# Set web caching to expire the same date every month for all users

Tags: php, caching, header

Right now we have a 1 month developing cycle for our web based service. Is it possible to set the headers so the cache will expire the 1st of every month for all users?
I know that we could set the expiration date to the 1st next month every time we make an update but I would want a more flexible solution.
So in short, can I in some way do this?

```
header("Expires: 1st/month 05:00:00 GMT"); // Expires the 1st of every month for everybody
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the code from [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777384/how-to-find-first-day-of-the-next-month-and-remain-days-to-this-date-with-php) to get a timestamp for the first day of the next month:

```
$curMonth = date('n');
$curYear  = date('Y');

if ($curMonth == 12)
    $firstDayNextMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $curYear+1);
else
    $firstDayNextMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $curMonth+1, 1);
```

Then, use that timestamp with `date()` to generate the date in the format required by the HTTP Expires header:

```
header('Expires: ' . date('D, d M Y', $firstDayNextMonth) . ' 05:00:00 GMT');
```