# 'Round' up a date to the beginning of the next month

Tags: php, date

I need to take an existing date from a variable and display a date that is always the 1st day (01) of whatever the next month is (and accounting for the year as well).

So if I have this:

```
$date = '2017-03-17'; // YYYY-MM-DD
```

I need to take that date and make it output this:

```
2017-04-01 // The first day of the next month
```

Just another example...

```
$date = '2017-12-23'; // YYYY-MM-DD
```

...should be converted to...

```
2018-01-01 // The first day of the next month
```

Comment: I think this may have already been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777384/how-to-find-first-day-of-the-next-month-and-remaining-days-till-this-date-with-p)

Comment: @ PhilS but i think @Matei Mihai answer is much better than that right answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find first day of the next month and remaining days till this date with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777384/how-to-find-first-day-of-the-next-month-and-remaining-days-till-this-date-with-p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use DateTime like:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2017-03-17');
$dateTime->modify('first day of next month');

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Another option to do the same.+1. :)

Comment: for making it look so fun+1

Answer (score 0):

Simply increment the date by `1` month and set the date to `1`st of the month. Do -

```
date('Y-m-01', strtotime('+1 MONTH', strtotime($date)));
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/790225)

Answer (score 0):

you can get it using

```
$date = '2017-03-17';
echo date('Y-m-01', strtotime('+1 month',strtotime($date)));
```

https://eval.in/790237

Comment: same answer posted below by @Sougata Bose

Comment: check the time who has posted earlier